# Delete Columns from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have a GridView with a couple of columns that I do not want to be exported to PDF (through iTextSharp).

How can I hide the columns I don't want exported before I export the data?

Answer (score 10):

Before exporting the data, do something like:

```
myGridView.columns.RemoveAt(index);    //Index is the index of the column you want to remove
myGridView.Databind();
```

Answer (score 2):

or try

```
  dataGridView1.Columns[index].Visible = false; // the index of the column to be hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite old but in the meantime there is another option:

```
myGridView.Columns.Remove(myGridView.Columns[3]) ;
```

or for vbnet:

```
myGridView.Columns.Remove(myGridView.Columns(3))
```

This removes the columns before the databind().
If you use the .Visible = false option, then during RowDataBound the column is still there .