# How to delete column from GridView where DataSource is a DataTable and AutoGenerateColumns is true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

Just wanted to know if this is possible with C#.

I have a GridView. The Datasource of the GridView is a DataTable generated from a Database. The AutoGenerateColumn is True.

Therefore when I try the following code

```
gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(1); //I got 12 Columns from the DataTable
```

I get the following error:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection.

I don't want to delete it from the DataTable. I want to delete the column before I use RenderControl to convert the GridView to html text. And I don't want the column to show up in html text. I tried doing this too:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows){
    row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

But it doesn't hide the Column Header.

Anyone have any idea if it is possible to delete column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Columns from GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215996/delete-columns-from-gridview)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Nope. Not a Duplicate. I already went through that question before posting this. That question didn't mentioned anything about DataSource as Datatable and AutoGenerateColumn attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gridView.columns.RemoveAt(1);
gridView.Databind();
```

Comment: Already Tried that. Are you saying try with gridView.columns (Columns starting with small letter 'c') ? I tried the Databind(). Didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: On GridView1.RowDataBound event

```
GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
```

OR

```
protected void bla_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; // hides the first column
}
```

Actually, RowCreated will be called several times each time the GridView renders. But it works